# Closure in Java or something like it

Tags: java, android, reflection, closures, anonymous-class

I have been trying to find a way to incorporate something similar to Closure in Java 1.6 since I'm developing for Android.

What I want (in a perfect world) I have a class, we will call it "Item".

I then have an arrayList of these.

```
ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<item>;
```

In each one of them items.get(x) I want to save a block of code that will be executed when called. This block of code needs to take place in the scope of the class housing the ArrayList items.

My only,  half brained idea, would be to create the methods in the class that housed "items" and save the name of the function in each of the "item" instances, then use reflection to call those methods....

I'm pretty doubtful that this could be possible, but this is the place I will find an answer either way.

Thanks ahead of time for any help.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but you might want to have a read through [Jon Skeet's article](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter5/closures.aspx), it covers Java as well (before Java 7).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you need is an interface like

```
interface Closure{
    public void exec();
}
```

and create an anonymous class for each "closure" code you want

```
Closure closure = new Closure() {
    public void exec(){
        // code here
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm, I'm trying to see how this will work, I think I'm being a little slow though. So in my Items class I would define the anonymous class? Wouldn't that limit the scope to only that Item instance?

Comment: um, if you want to define the anonymous class in `Item`, then you can change `exec` signature to accept inputs and call `exec` with whatever you want to pass.

Comment: Well there is the problem for me, I want these blocks of code to be able to access the variables that are in the class that houses the array List. So I would need the code to be called defined in that housing class, but saved in the item class. I feel like I am asking too much. haha

Comment: Alright, I got a chance to work on this again and it works. I set up the Interface in it's own file. Added a variable of interface "Closure" and added it to the constructor method. When creating the Item instance, I just use new Closure(){ @Override public void exec(){}} in the constructor and it works perfectly. Thanks for your help!